# In settings, "Enable keyboard shortcuts" requires refresh before it works

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts

Within the user profile → *Settings* → *Preferences* → under *Interface*, the "Enable keyboard shortcuts" requires a hard refresh of the page before you can start using shortcuts (in Firefox on OS X at least).

I clicked "enable keyboard shortcuts", but it does not work until a hard refresh of the page occurs. When I first enabled it from the settings page, it looked like the functionality was broken. Likewise, disabling shortcuts does not take affect until a hard refresh of the page has occurred.

Comment: For Firefox, `hard refresh` is `CTRL`+`F5`

Comment: Thanks though the functionality should not require a refresh in order to work.